# mystackwalker.cxx(29) : error C3861: 'CaptureStackBackTrace': identifier not found

Tags: c++, dll, stack-trace

I am using CaptureStackBackTrace to create my own stack trace. But when I compile my code it says "error C3861: 'CaptureStackBackTrace': identifier not found". I have already included winbase.h. And also checked kernel32.dll, its there in my system.

But When I checked msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633%28VS.85%29.aspx, it says Kernel32.dll. I am confused whether Kernel32.dll is same as kernel32.dll. If they are same then what could be the problem. If no then from where I could get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `kernel.dll`. If identifier is not found it most likely means you didn't set version macros properly (see [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). Since the function is marked as available from XP onwards, the macros must point to at least XP for the function to be declared.

Comment: sorry I missed it, its kernel32.dll